# Python - tkinter.messagebox cannot see title and showerror icon in macOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, python-3.8, tkmessagebox

I use tkinter to do GUI. When use messagebox, that can not see title and showerror icon  is a file, just like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxg5f.png)

This is my env:

1. macOS / windows 10
2. python 3.8.13
3. tk 8.6

And this is my code

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.withdraw()
messagebox.showerror(title="error title", message="for test message")
window.destroy()
```

I want to see title and error icon, just like windows system.
How can I do to fix this progrem, thanks.

Comment: not sure i understand the question. there is an error box....

Comment: In windows, the error box has title and message, but macOS only show message on box. And windows has an error icon, macOS is a file icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file=your path))
messagebox.showerror(title="error title", message="for test message")
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, PhotoImage(file=your path))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are features that are different for different operating systems, then you can determine the operating system like this:

```py
import sys

p = sys.platform

if p == "linux" or p == "linux2":
    # linux
    print('using linux')
elif p == "darwin":
    # OS X
    print('using mac')
elif p == "win32":
    # Windows...
    print('using windows')
```

Alternatively the mac settings (so not `tkinter`). How are the error messages currently displayed on the pc as one would expect `tkinter` to be consistent with this.